# Do we know anything about the source material for the Old Testament?

Tags: history, old-testament

The historical books especially fit so cleanly together that it would seem like possibly a whole bunch of historical records, traditions, and books were collected and form the source material. Otherwise I would expect it would look a lot more like the New Testament - a more or less loose collection of stories, letters, prophecies. Duplicate stories, and so on.

I know some scholars believe such a compilation happened as late as in the Babylonian Exile, but is anything actually known about source materials?

By that I mean, for example, stories about the Judges predating the Babylonian Exile, or stories about David or something like that.

Comment: As you must know, the historical books contain many references to other books such as those listed [here](https://www.blueletterbible.org/Comm/stewart_don/faq/right-books-in-old-testament/question11-non-canonical-books-old-testament.cfm).  Unfortunately it seems most of those either books perished or parts of them incorporated into other non-canonical books.

Comment: The O.T. itself mentions some sources, such as the Book of Jasher Joshua 10:13, and other writings about the kings of Israel, but there can only be speculation and opinions about those and other possible sources. Certainly, knowledge about the  opening chapters of Genesis must initially have been oral. But why on earth would you expect the O.T. to be more like the N.T. "a loose collection" ! "duplicate stories"- much of the writings about the kings of Israel are duplicated in part, yet with distinctive features, as with the gospel accounts. I'm struggling to get a handle on this Q.

Comment: In 1946 one of the most remarkable archeological finds in history gave a great more biblical 'source material'. You can read more about it here - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_Sea_Scrolls

Comment: @Anne Sure, Kings1/2 is duplicated with Chronicles, but in the end, disregard all that commentary - the question is along the lines of do we know documents that we assume to be source material for the OT?

Comment: This is a good question but we don't even have any NT autographs and there is scanty extra-biblical evidence for King David (which is not proof against). +1